# Uniting JsonResult why can't I get access through dynamic if the items are an anonymous type

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, dynamic

I had a method looking like:

```
public JsonResult GetSpecies()
        {
            var species = new List<SpeciesType> {
                                                new SpeciesType{ Id=1, Name="Giraffe" },
                                                new SpeciesType{ Id=2, Name="Wolf" }
                                            };

            return Json(new { Species = species });
        }
```

Then I had the assembly this is in make its internals visible to my test project and had a test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GetSpecies_ReturnsJsonVersionOfNameAndId()
        {
            ...

            var result = controller.GetSpecies();

            dynamic data = result.Data;

            Assert.AreEqual(1, data.Species[0].Id);
            Assert.AreEqual("Giraffe", data.Species[0].Name);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, data.Species[1].Id);
            Assert.AreEqual("Wolf", data.Species[1].Name);
        }
```

So this worked fine.

I altered the method to return anonymous types in the array:

```
public JsonResult GetSpecies()
            {
                var species = new List<SpeciesType> {
                                                    new SpeciesType{ Id=1, Name="Giraffe" },
                                                    new SpeciesType{ Id=2, Name="Wolf" }
                                                }.Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name });

                return Json(new { Species = species });
            }
```

The test now throws exceptions.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix?

Comment: *What* exception is thrown?

Comment: @JonSkeet - The exception is Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: sorry just updated the question because there were a couple of errors in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're now not providing a `List<T>` - your `Species` property is just a sequence. I don't know how it's representing in JSON, and if it *actually* went across the wire, it might be okay - but it's probably simplest to just make sure that the `Species` value is actually a list:

```
var species = new List<SpeciesType> {
                                    new SpeciesType{ Id=1, Name="Giraffe" },
                                    new SpeciesType{ Id=2, Name="Wolf" }
                                }
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @user2005657: Right - will remove the last part now :)